# Does it need a try catch block

Tags: java

I am getting the total bytes of the directoreis and files from a different Windows server but not sure if I need to have a try catch block in these 2 method? Please help

```
private void retrieveTotalBytes(File sourceFile)
{
    File[] files = sourceFile.listFiles();
    for(File file : files)
    {
        if(file.isDirectory()) 
            retrieveTotalBytes(file);
        else totalBytes += file.length();
    }
}

private void copyFiles(File sourceFile, File targetFile) throws IOException
{
    if(sourceFile.isDirectory())
    {
        if(!targetFile.exists()) targetFile.mkdirs();

        String[] filePaths = sourceFile.list();
        for(String filePath : filePaths)
        {                                 
            File srcFile = new File(sourceFile, filePath);
            File destFile = new File(targetFile, filePath);

            copyFiles(srcFile, destFile);
        }
    }
    else
    { }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to close this question

Comment: @PreetSangha, agreed. this is a legitimate question... and a good one at that

Comment: what do you mean with "need"? In order for the code to compile? Or in order to be pretty?

Comment: Need in the sense, is it mandatory to have try catch, as I am getting files from a different windows server

Comment: How can this fall under the 'not a real question?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several choices.

1) Catch and handle (creates a need for logging at this low level).

This is only really a solution if the error is irrelevant to the operation of the code (which it probably isn't)

2) Catch and re-throw as an application specific Exception.

This allows you to build the exception inside an 'ApplicationException' tree and catch it along with other exceptions.

3) Catch and re-throw as a RuntimeException.

As you probably already do all the checks to ensure that the file is readable, the directory is manageable etc, there is no practical reason for it to throw an error. If it does throw one, you may not be able to recover from it. If you can't, you would end up throwing 'IOException' all the way up the stack, which is stupid.

Instead you can re-throw this 'unrecoverable' as a RuntimeException and catch it at a really high level, chuck out a dialog box and crash.

4) Throw the plain IO Exception and pass the problem up the chain.

This isn't solving the problem, it's merely moving it up your application (and allowing the IOException to bleed into your codebase).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you would need to inside these functions because they are lower (assume that the client is smart enough to make these responsible decisions).  But you might consider doing it at higher levels which call these functions.

for example . . .

```
File data, destination;

try { copyFiles(data, destination); }
catch (IOException e) { . . . }


// and. . .

try { retrieveTotalBytes(data); }
catch (Exception e) { . . . };
```

. . . but it is up to you